# Are there any Third-Party Apple Watch apps that render HTML emails and provide push notifications?

Tags: mail.app, software-recommendation, apple-watch, watchos, mobile-mail

Since Gmail as a service does not support push on iOS Mail, I do not get notifications for emails as they come in unless I use a third-party email app. I have used Outlook for iOS for a long time now, and it has worked great. However, I recently got an Apple Watch, and I was disappointed to find that the Watch app for Outlook does not render HTML in emails. The emails are plain text only.

From what I have seen so far, the built-in Mail app on Apple Watch does a good job of rendering HTML emails. I have not had any luck finding a third-party app that can do this, though, so that I can get both HTML rendering and push notifications for email.

Do any Watch apps that render HTML emails exist, or does Apple not allow third-party email apps to render HTML for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Watch OS (watchOS) does permit rendering HTML email.  However, the Watch app must be built using watchOS 5 and use Webkit for the email.  It's also a poor experience to try to read html-formatted email on a small Watch screen.

Third-party developers do not have access to WebKit or other means of HTML rendering on Apple Watch as of watchOS 9, so you won't be able to find a mail app that renders HTML correctly besides the built-in one.

Comment: This seems like an outdated copy-paste answer  WatchOS 5 is not new; we are on 6 now. The experience in the built-in Mail app is not that bad, and someone could certainly have made a third-party app with HTML rendering in the year or so since Watch got Webkit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is false. Although WebKit is available on watchOS, it is restricted to the first-party Mail and Messages apps only. (See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698287)

Comment: @IntelCorei9 The answer isn't 'false'. It was written years ago and was accurate when it was written. If you have updated info, don't add a comment, edit the answer to improve it.

Comment: @fsb The information was never accurate. WebKit was never on the watchOS SDK, so only Apple can use it. Thus that part in particular is false. An edit has been requested.

Comment: @IntelCorei9 As always, if you have better/newer info, edit the answer instead of leaving comments. I approved your edit to the answer.

Comment: It would be better as a separate answer @IntelCorei9 since there are still people with Watch OS 5 and rewriting this perfectly valid answer would make that info inaccessible.  A new answer would preserve the timeline of watchOS versions.